# From which scripture is this Mahiṣāsura Mardini Stotram come from?

Tags: shiva, durga, parvati, uma

अयि गिरिनन्दिनि नन्दितमेदिनि विश्वविनोदिनि नन्दिनुते गिरिवरविन्ध्यशिरोऽधिनिवासिनि विष्णुविलासिनि जिष्णुनुते । भगवति हे शितिकण्ठकुटुम्बिनि भूरिकुटुम्बिनि भूरिकृते जय जय हे महिषासुरमर्दिनि रम्यकपर्दिनि शैलसुते ॥

Is this mantra independent or is authenticated by any shastra??

What does viṣṇu vilasini means here in this line? I saw some vaiṣṇavas use it to show durga is consort of Viṣṇu. How could it be possible as I saw durga is mother of Ganesha and Kartikeya and sister of Nārāyaṇa called as Narayani !!

Comment: As far as the popular notion is concerned, this is attributed to *Adi Shankaracharya*

Comment: The nāma Vishnu-vilasini refers to Devi as the Yogamaya of Lord Vishnu, this is paralleled in the Lalita Sahasranamam as well, which calls Lalitambika as Vishnumaya-vilasini.

Answer (score 6):

*Contrary to Popular Opinion, Mahisasura Mardini stotram is not an independent composition. It is A completely Shāstrokta stuti, directly found in the Śiva Rahasya Itihāsa that was sung by the Devas as a stuti for none other than Bhagavatī Pārvatī.
Here is the Direct reference :-*

---

### [Śiva Rahasya Itihāsa, Amsha 1, Chapter 53](https://archive.org/details/eGcz_shiva-rahasya-maha-itihasa-maheshwar-part-1-jangamwadi-math-collection/page/n211/mode/2up?view=theater)

[image]

---

*It can be clearly seen from the above that the Shāstrokta Mahisasuramardini stotram instead of '*विष्णुविलासिनि जिष्णुनुते*' mentions '*शम्भुविलासिनि विष्णुनुते* in the concerned verse which translates to "She who is The Giver of Joy to Shambhu (Shiva) and who is praised by Vishnu", thereby leaving absolutely no doubts that the deity eulogized through this stotra is Bhagavatī Pārvatī, the consort of Bhagavana Shiva.*

---